# Openfaas, custom metrics

Tags: prometheus, openfaas

Folks,
What is the recommended way of sending application telemetry in OpenFaas functions?  Doesnt OpenFaas already have Prometheus, thus you should be able to push custom metrics to it?   Or do you have to use some form of a push approach such as statsD?

What are the options?

Thank you!